# Cannot scroll RecyclerView inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am having troubles integrating a RecyclerView (using cardviews for the rows) inside a fragment. For some reason I cannot scroll the card view? Please, any suggestions?

This is my app design:

[image]

This is my fragment code:

```
public class PageFragment2 extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE2 = "ARG_PAGE";
private int mPage2;

public static PageFragment2 newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE2, page);
    PageFragment2 fragment = new PageFragment2();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage2 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE2);

    Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate" + mPage2);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page2,container,false);

    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) view;
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Georgi Koemdzhiev");
    names.add("Mariya Menova");
    names.add("Simeon Simeonov");
    names.add("Ivan Dqkov");
    names.add("Dymityr Vasilev");
    names.add("Petar Dimov");
    CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(names);

    recList.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("MainActivity","onCreateView" + mPage2);
    return view;
}
}
```

This is my fragment XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/cardList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

My activity_main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="koemdzhiev.com.newtablayouttest.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

Comment: why do you need a relativeLayout? get rid of it

Comment: @injecteer I don't know why I added it. I removed it but the problem still exists. I updated my question with the changes.

Comment: try addind `llm.setOrienation( HORIZONTAL )`

Comment: @injecteer for some reason that worked and I am scrolling. However, I want to scroll vertically. I did try setting it to verticle but it does not work still...

Comment: It's kinda small mistake. Don't wrap your content area with `AppBarLayout` as sorianiv's answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Activity from the "Tabbed Activity" template, which contains the ViewPager which is containing your Fragment, uses an AppBarLayout.

This AppBarLayout is stealing the vertical movement, since it doesn't know there's a scrollable nested view (the RecyclerView) inside the ViewPager. Remove the AppBarLayout from the XML file of your Activity (you can take the TabLayout and ToolBar to the upper level).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not exactly sure what you are suggesting. I have included my activity_main xml code as well. Could you tell me specify what I need to change, please? :)

Comment: it's ok, I just wrapped my TabLayout and ViewPager in a LinierView out of the AppBarLayout and now works fine. Thanks!