# Scrolling Problem of RecyclerView inside TabLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

Below is the XML code for TabLayout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bapji.cubeon.FirstFragment"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/any">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/any"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/any"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the XML code for RecyclerView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/solve_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I am not able to scroll this RecyclerView while in the TabLayout I am only getting fixed items of that RecyclerView and rest items i am not able to see so if anyone can help me solve this problem will be helpful to me.

Edit - ScreenShot of problem

[ScreenShot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qURIx.png)

Below is code for FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public SectionPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter java code

```
public class SolveAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SolveAdapter.SolveViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<EachTime> mSolves;

public SolveAdapter(Context context, List<EachTime> mSolves) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mSolves = mSolves;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public SolveViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View layout;
    layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_each_time,parent,false);



    return new SolveViewHolder(layout);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SolveViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.eachSolveTime.setText(mSolves.get(position).getCount());
    holder.eachSolveScramble.setText(mSolves.get(position).getScramble());
    holder.eachSolveDate.setText(mSolves.get(position).getDate());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSolves.size();
}

public class SolveViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView eachSolveTime,eachSolveDate,eachSolveScramble;

    public SolveViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        eachSolveDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.each_solve_date);
        eachSolveScramble = itemView.findViewById(R.id.each_solve_scramble);
        eachSolveTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.each_solve_title);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set **android:layout_height="0dp"** on **ViewPager** because you use **android:layout_weight="1"** in your xml code

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/any"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Edit --

i think your question is duplicate to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831320/cannot-scroll-recyclerview-inside-a-fragment)

Comment: Its still the same i am not able to scroll through whole list

Comment: @devamdarji22 are your sure your  items in recyclerView  more than height of phone screen ?

Comment: @devamdarji22 can add screen shot for your screen hole code for adapter

Comment: @devamdarji22 yes please

Comment: yes i have edited question and added screenshot of problem which i am facing

Comment: RecyclerView adapter friend  not fragment

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, I solve this issue by including a nested scroll view hope it will helpful to you.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size20"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size20"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size20"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size10" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add off-page limit then Please remove the view pager off-page limit.
e.g viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); remove this line or comment then try.

```
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
```

//.     Comment the below line in your code
//      viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

```
    final MyAdapter1 adapter = new MyAdapter1(this,ArtistActivity.this, 
          tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And After this add Nested ScrollView in your XML :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Please Also add this line : android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in your RecyclerView.